# How to speed up LINQ WHERE?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, lambda

I have run a profiler on my .NET winforms app (compiled with .NET 4.7.1) and it is pointing at the following function as consuming 73% of my application's CPU time, which seems like far too much for a simple utility function:

```
public static bool DoesRecordExist(string keyColumn1, string keyColumn2, string keyColumn3,
        string keyValue1, string keyValue2, string keyValue3, DataTable dt)
{
    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
        bool exists = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(r =>
                string.Equals(SafeTrim(r[keyColumn1]), keyValue1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                string.Equals(SafeTrim(r[keyColumn2]), keyValue2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                string.Equals(SafeTrim(r[keyColumn3]), keyValue3, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            )
            .Any();
        return exists;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The purpose of this function is to pass in some key column names and matching key values, and checking whether any matching record exists in the in-memory c# `DataTable`.

My app is processing hundreds of thousands of records and for each record, this function must be called multiple times. The app is doing a lot of inserts, and before any insert, it must check whether that record already exists in the database. I figured that an in-memory check against the `DataTable` would be much faster than going back to the physical database each time, so that's why I'm doing this in-memory check. Each time I do a database insert, I do a corresponding insert into the `DataTable`, so that subsequent checks as to whether the record exists will be accurate.

So to my question: *Is there a faster approach?* (I don't think I can avoid checking for record existence each and every time, else I'll end up with duplicate inserts and key violations.)

**EDIT #1**
In addition to trying the suggestions that have been coming in, which I'm trying now, it occurred to me that I should also maybe do the `.AsEnumerable()` only once and pass in the `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>` instead of the `DataTable`. Do you think this will help?

**EDIT #2**
I just did a controlled test and found that querying the database directly to see if a record already exists is *dramatically slower* than doing an in-memory lookup.

Comment: Do you need to do all of this on so many records in memory? C# isn't going to be nearly as efficient as say, SQL would be. I ran into a similar problem recently where a stored proc was offloading hundreds of thousands of records into a C# app that did all of the filtering. Refactoring that so SQL did most of the filtering sped things up by at least a magnitude of 10.

Comment: But going back to the DB every time would be far slower, wouldn't it? The datatable is already filtered - there are no unnecessary records in there.

Comment: No the idea is to do the WHERE clause on the SQL server and get the result set in one round trip.  You could do this in Entity Framework, in Linq2Sql or even in Dapper.  The first 2 (EF and L2S) translate your LINQ statements into expressions which are marshaled to the server as TSQL statements and executed there.  Dapper expects you to write your query as parameterized SQL.

Comment: Remove the where , put the Any instead with the condition

Comment: @HerrimanCoder have you actually profiled the difference between running the queries in-memory, or against the database?

Comment: canton7: no I haven't, but I'm willing to try. Flydog57, the WHERE clause changes for each record, that's the whole point. It can't be done on the initial query. Example: 'select ID from MyTable where ID = 123' (check whether it already exists) - while record inserts are continuously happening in the app.

Comment: I wonder what the performance hit would be for 3 cascading Where clauses.  `.Where(string.Equal).Where(string.Equal).Where(string.Equal).Any()`?

Comment: Calling `AsEnumerable` only once won't make much of a difference. It only returns a lazy-view to the underlying table.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder you'll find that running a query in the database, with the benefit of indexes, a lot of memory, multiple cores, and a data connection that runs at 500MB/s or faster is exponentially faster than pulling all that data over a slow network connection and then scanning all that data in memory without any indexes. If the three key columns are part of the primary key, the query will probably be instantaneous.

Comment: Panagiotis, I'm going to try this, but I want to be sure that I was clear that "pulling all that data over a slow network" only happens once. And it comes over in seconds. It's the processing of hundreds of thousands of records, and the related `DoesRecordExist()` calls where the slowness occurs. Having said that, do you still think direct DB queries will be faster?

Comment: I just did a controlled test and found that querying the database directly to see if a record already exists is dramatically slower than doing an in-memory lookup.

Comment: Make sure the query can be processed by the database. Including the trim probably requires fetching all records. When using proper indexes and a single sql query should be faster. Know what you’re doing is key here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try parallel execution, this should be a very good case for that as you mentioned you are working with a huge set, and no orderliness is needed if you just want to check if a record already exists.

```
bool exists = dt.AsEnumerable().AsParallel().Any((r =>
            string.Equals(SafeTrim(r[keyColumn1]), keyValue1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(SafeTrim(r[keyColumn2]), keyValue2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(SafeTrim(r[keyColumn3]), keyValue3, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        )
```

Comment: Nice work iSpain17, the combination of `Any()` (instead of `Where()...Any()`) and AsParallele() brought significant performance improvement!

Comment: Using more cores to distribute inefficient algorithms is not the answer. Better think to create more efficient algorithms...

Comment: Ramon is absolutely right in the context that it could be even faster, should there exist a faster algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution find all occurences which evaluates true in the condition and then you ask if there is any. Instead use Any directly. Replace Where with Any. It will stop processing when hits first true evaulation of the condition.

```
bool exists = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(r => condition);
```

Comment: yeah, same when you use list.Where().FirstOrDefault(), remove the where and put the condition in the Any

Comment: I would suggest you to look at the source code for Any (you can do so [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1288)). Omitting Where is just a shorthand

Comment: This should not make much of a difference, if any at all. `Where` will only process elements as long as none of them reach `Any`. That's the power of Linq.

Comment: `IEnumerable` is lazy, so it will only fetch a new record when you asked it to. If the `Any()` call returns true, then it won't ask for new records anymore. Your suggestion is a bit cleaner though, but it won't make much of a difference in terms of performance.

Comment: This change alone improved performance 15%, which is good. I'll accept your answer if this is the extent of what I can do. Lukas, is there anything else I can do to speed things up?

Comment: Do you benchmark in Release mode? With optimizations it should be identical.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you are keeping the key columns of the existing records in a `HashSet`. I'm using tuples here, but you could also create your own `Key` struct or class by overriding `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.

```
private HashSet<(string, string, string)> _existingKeys =
    new HashSet<(string, string, string)>();
```

Then you can test the existence of a key very quickly with

```
if (_existingKeys.Contains((keyValue1, keyValue2, keyValue3))) {
    ...
}
```

Don't forget to keep this `HashSet` in sync with your additions and deletions. Note that tuples cannot be compared with `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`. Therefore either convert all the keys to lower case, or use the custom struct approach where you can use the desired comparison method.

```
public readonly struct Key
{
    public Key(string key1, string key2, string key3) : this()
    {
        Key1 = key1?.Trim() ?? "";
        Key2 = key2?.Trim() ?? "";
        Key3 = key3?.Trim() ?? "";
    }

    public string Key1 { get; }
    public string Key2 { get; }
    public string Key3 { get; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Key)) {
            return false;
        }

        var key = (Key)obj;
        return
            String.Equals(Key1, key.Key1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
            String.Equals(Key2, key.Key2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
            String.Equals(Key3, key.Key3, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashCode = -2131266610;
        unchecked {
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(Key1);
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(Key2);
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(Key3);
        }
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Another question is whether it is a good idea to use the current culture when comparing db keys. Users with different cultures might get different results. Better explicitly specify the same culture used by the db.

Comment: Note that the OP carefully uses `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` for his comparisons, which he'll lose here. It's easy to get back with a custom struct though.

Comment: That won't work -- StringComparison can't compare tuples

Comment: Implement `IEquatable<T>` otherwise your struct is going to be boxed all over the place, which negates the point of it being a struct (see my answer for a reference)

Comment: I'm not sure a HashSet approach will work, because my DataTables almost always contain more columns than just the keys, and I need to access those columns' values at times.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you want to transpose your data structure. Instead of having a DataTable where each row has `keyColumn1`, `keyColumn2` and `keyColumn3`, have 3 `HashSet<string>`, where the first contains all of the `keyColumn1` values, etc.

Doing this should be a lot faster than iterating through each of the rows:

```
var hashSetColumn1 = new HashSet<string>(
    dt.Rows.Select(x => x[keyColumn1]),
   StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

var hashSetColumn2 = new HashSet<string>(
    dt.Rows.Select(x => x[keyColumn2]),
   StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

var hashSetColumn3 = new HashSet<string>(
    dt.Rows.Select(x => x[keyColumn3]),
   StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Obviously, create these once, and then maintain them (as you're currently maintaining your DataTable). They're expensive to create, but cheap to query.

Then:

```
bool exists = hashSetColumn1.Contains(keyValue1) &&
    hashSetColumn2.Contains(keyValue2) &&
    hashSetColumn3.Contains(keyValue3);
```

Alternatively (and more cleanly), you can define your own struct which contains values from the 3 columns, and use a single HashSet:

```
public struct Row : IEquatable<Row>
{
    // Convenience
    private static readonly IEqualityComparer<string> comparer = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIngoreCase;

    public string Value1 { get; }
    public string Value2 { get; }
    public string Value3 { get; }

    public Row(string value1, string value2, string value3)
    {
        Value1 = value1;
        Value2 = value2;
        Value3 = value3;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Row row && Equals(row);

    public bool Equals(Row other)
    {
        return comparer.Equals(Value1, other.Value1) &&
               comparer.Equals(Value2, other.Value2) &&
               comparer.Equals(Value3, other.Value3);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + comparer.GetHashCode(Value1);
            hash = hash * 23 + comparer.GetHashCode(Value2);
            hash = hash * 23 + comparer.GetHashCode(Value3);
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Row left, Row right) => left.Equals(right);
    public static bool operator !=(Row left, Row right) => !(left == right);
}
```

Then you can make a:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<Row>(dt.Select(x => new Row(x[keyColumn1], x[keyColumn2], x[keyColumn3]));
```

And cache that. Query it like:

```
hashSet.Contains(new Row(keyValue1, keyValue2, keyValue3));
```

Comment: It should be noted that the HashSets should be created only when needed, not in every single call to the method

Comment: Essentially, you're creating an in-memory index for your table that is being recreated every time the table is fetched. I only think this solution is a suitable option if the table is read-only and the `DoesRecordExist` method needs to invoked very often.

Comment: Agreed, I recommended profiling directly against the database in a comment on the OP, and I still think it's likely going to be quicker than all of this...

Comment: In-memory SQLite databases also perform incredibly well for stuff like this, if you really need it

Answer (score 0):

In some cases using LINQ won't optimize as good as a sequential query, so you might be better of writing the query just the old-fashined way:

```
public static bool DoesRecordExist(string keyColumn1, string keyColumn2, string keyColumn3,
        string keyValue1, string keyValue2, string keyValue3, DataTable dt)
{
    if (dt != null) 
    {
        foreach (var r in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (string.Equals(SafeTrim(r[keyColumn1]), keyValue1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                string.Equals(SafeTrim(r[keyColumn2]), keyValue2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                string.Equals(SafeTrim(r[keyColumn3]), keyValue3, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But there might be more structural improvements, but this depends on the situation whether you can use it.

**Option 1: Making the selection already in the database**
You are using a `DataTable`, so there is a chance that you fetch the data from the database. If you have a lot of records, then it might make more sense to move this check to the database. When using the proper indexes it might be way faster then an in-memory tablescan.

**Option 2: Replace `string.Equals+SafeTrim` with a custom method**
You are using `SafeTrim` up to three times per row, which creates a lot of new strings. When you create your own method that compares both strings (string.Equals) with respect to leading/trailing whitespaces (SafeTrim), but *without* creating a new string then this could be way faster, reduce memory load and reduce garbage collection. If the implementation is good enough to inline, then you'll gain a lot of performance.

**Option 3: Check the columns in the proper order**
Make sure you use the proper order and specify the column that has the least probability to match as `keyColumn1`. This will make the if-statement result to false sooner. If `keyColumn1` matches in 80% of the cases, then you need to perform a lot more comparisons.

Comment: Three downvotes and no comment why... The simple answer (use more cores) is for lazy programmers. Better think of more efficient algorithms...

Comment: I've no idea why you're getting downvoted: removing linq from a hot path is a perfectly valid answer